# UIScrollView Child Has Coordinates Inversed

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView as a child to a ViewController.view and for some reason the coordinates system within the UISCrollView seem to be inversed? Is there a reason for this?

When I add UILabels or UIImages to the UISCrollView it seems to add in the inverse.

A statement like this

```
tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
CGRectMake(tempImage.frame.origin.x,
           tempImage.frame.origin.y + tempImage.frame.size.height * 1.5,
           80, 
           25)];
```

Add the label to the top left of the image rather than below to the middle. What could be causing the coordinates to be flipped?

Comment: Can you NSLog tempImages bounds before this call is made? Also why are you doing `tempImage.frame.origin.y + tempImage.frame.size.height * 1.5` instead of `tempImage.frame.origin.y + tempImage.frame.size.height/2` like for your width?

Comment: I want to place the UILabel in the middle of the Image width and below the image itself. /2 will place it on the exact middle of both axes, on top of the image.

Comment: how are you adding it? `[scrollView addSubView:tempLabel];`? if you try to add it as a subView of the image, it will do that weird snap to upper left thing since it doesn't lie inside the view you are trying to add it to completely.

Comment: Looks like I mistakenly added it to the self.view and also I had miss-clicked the origin in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Origin" attribute in the interface builder, make sure it's in the upper left as you expect:
[image]